# SSH2 Not Working On New Server

Tags: php, libssh2, ssh2-sftp

We have changed hosting companies and where ssh2 was working it no longer works. We have `ssh2` enabled on the new server along with `allow_url_fopen` enabled.

The only difference I can see is that the old server used `PHP 5.4.45` and the new server is using `PHP 5.6.28`.

However, I now get the following error.
`Could not open remote file: ssh2.sftp://Resource id #337/my/directory/file.txt`

Here is an example of my code:

```
$remote_host = "myhostinfohere";
$remote_port = 22;
$remote_user = "myuser";
$remote_pass = "mypassword";
$remote_dir = "/my/directory/";
$remote_file = 'file.txt';

try {
    $remote_conn = ssh2_connect($remote_host, $remote_port);    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("could not connect to ".$remote_host);
}

try {
    ssh2_auth_password($remote_conn, $remote_user, $remote_pass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Password failed on ".$remote_host);
}

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($remote_conn);

$fetch_string = "ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . $remote_dir . $remote_file;

//If I add this it says it doesn't exists for some reason even though I can see the file if I log in remotely.
$fileExists = file_exists($fetch_string);
if (!$fileExists) { 
    die('File does not exist');
}

$stream = fopen($fetch_string, 'r');

if (!$stream) {
    die("Could not open remote file: " . $fetch_string . "\n");
}
```

Again, this same code works on the old server but doesn't on the new server. What am I missing? I can easily copy the file to my server with `ssh2_scp_recv()` which works fine so I'm not sure what is happening with the `fopen()` function.

Comment: can you manually authenticate using the same user/pass on the new server?  does /my/directory/file.txt exist on the new server? Does it have appropriate permissions?

Comment: I can manually authenticate and the connection does work. When I say new server I mean where the script is at that is used to call the other server. The other server where the file exists hasn't changed at all. Just the server that hosted the above script.

Comment: disable firewall and see the effect (the server where SSH script is). oh you already can make SSH request successfully right?. If so then that might be the file permission issue as mentioned by @ivanivan.

Comment: Which server, the one that hosts the above script? Unfortunately, I cannot disable the firewall on the server that contains the file.

Comment: the server where your SSH script (above script is) ...

Comment: Having some trouble disabling it but I ran this and executed the script and didn't see any errors. `sudo tail -f /var/log/messages |grep FIREWALL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of trying different options I finally ran across this. http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php

I changed this:
    `$fetch_string = "ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . $remote_dir . $remote_file;`

To this:
    `$fetch_string = "ssh2.sftp://user:password@mywebsiteorip.com" . $remote_dir . $remote_file;`

And presto the `fopen()` function started working.

I'm not sure if in the newer versions if they just deprecated the `ssh2_sftp()` function or if it is just a bug like @billynoah mentioned because the above link wasn't even using it.

I know how much of a pain this was so hopefully it will help someone else!

Comment: that's pretty cool - i'll have to give it a whirl in the php7 / wordpress install and see if it helps.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, as weird as the solution seems - had the same problem after switching from 5.4 to 5.6.30-something - none of the ssh2_* methods worked, the only solution was to use the full url in fopen.

Answer (score 3):

Here $fetch_string = "ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . $remote_dir . $remote_file;

use intval($sftp) instead of $sftp

Comment: This solution work for me.
Thanks to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73597

Answer (score 1):

Very likely related to this bug in the ssh2 extension - which I just recently encountered:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71376

And which breaks ssh2 update functionality in Wordpress:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35517

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you! I have not seen that until now. Let me do some further digging.

Comment: I just verified that I can use `ssh2_scp_recv()` to copy the file to my server although I prefer to use `fopen()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and I struggled a lot. For me its fixed now.
This is what I did: 
My PHP version: **5.6.25** 
Downloaded the latest php_ssh2.dll from:  https://phpfashion.com/php-ssh2-dll-for-php-5-6-and-7-0 (php_ssh2.dll for PHP 5.6 x64)
Replaced the **php_ssh2.dll** in the following location : *"C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext"* & restarted all my services.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that sftp service is enabled on the (Powershell) server